# How to access a varible from an node.js in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

How can i display a variable from a node.js route in a HTML File?

i have a node.js route like:

```
router.post("/login", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const formData = req.body
        const name = formData.name
        const pass = formData.password
        const checkUser = await user.findOne({name: name})
        const checkPass = await user.findOne({password: pass});
      
        if(checkUser && checkPass){
            session=req.session;
            session.userid=req.body.name;            
            console.log(session.userid);
            //res.send("Welcome User <a href=\'/logout'>click to logout</a>");
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/admin.html'));
        }
        else{
          res.send(`Use not registered`);
            console.log(name)
        }
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
})
```

i want to display the `session.userid` in my HTML file. How can i access the variable in noide.js?

in the top of my node.js file i have a variable `var session;`

and in my HTML file i have the script:

```
<script>
      function setUsername() {
      var number = "username";
      document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = session.userid;
    }
</script>
```

how can i set the `var number = session.userid` in order to display the logged name in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look up [EJS](https://ejs.co/). Its basically `HTML` with a little more syntax to to embedded JavaScript operations. You can serve `EJS` files from an `Express` server the exact same way as `HTML` files, but you can also [pass props and access the variables in the EJS file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-js-variables-accessible-to-ejs-files/).

Alternatively, you can make pass your `session id` to the client via a `client cookie` with [cookie-session](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html). Just make sure `httpOnly` is false so that JavaScript on the client can [access the cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Thank you. With `EJS` template its very easy. It help me a lot.